# How often a post WWII US president said publicly that the leader of another country must go? (e.g. "For God’s sake, this man cannot remain in power")

Tags: united-states, president, international-relations, history, regime-change

US President Biden concluded his March 27, 2022 speech in Poland with the words

> For God’s sake, this man cannot remain in power.

(e.g. CBS News's video [Biden says Putin "cannot remain in power"](https://youtu.be/UbpNWyV6rKc?t=1597) at 26:37)

**Question:** How often has a post WWII US president said publicly that the leader of another country must go?

I'm not asking about actions (covert or otherwise), I'm asking about highly visible public statements in a speech or via a definitive statement by an official White House spokesperson that the leader of a country must no longer be its leader in no uncertain terms.

Comment: Is restricting to post-WWII necessary? I doubt it would have been common prior.

Comment: @benjimin The question seems to be about US president saing it in the public and not just telling CIA to get rid of a leader he don´t like.

Comment: @benjimin the world got a lot smaller after WWII, the reach of the US got a lot bigger, and international reporting and awareness expanded, so US presidents were likely more measured in their challenges to other leaders and a statement like this would be much more significant. This is Politics SE not History SE so I think the postwar period is a good constraint.

Comment: and @convert makes a good point, the US "used to" just quietly *do stuff* rather than talk about it.

Comment: FWIW, the White House has since released a statement clarifying that [they are **not** in fact making regime change a policy goal](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/white-house-says-biden-is-not-calling-regime-change-russia-2022-03-26/) at this time, like this Q currently implies, and this should be viewed as a statement about his exercise of power over his neighbors, not in Russia itself. (I understand that's arguably not what he said, but not every President is known for being a precise communicator.)

Comment: @uhoh - Last paragraph says this question is about calls for "regime change".  That's the exact phrase the WH denied this was.

Comment: @T.E.D. yes now I see what you mean, it doesn't any more :-)

Comment: @T.E.D.: TBH it's probably another case of Biden "speaking his heart", like with the war crimes, which the WH also walked back (of sorts) later.

Comment: @benjimin: I wouldn't be so sure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_involvement_in_regime_change#1900s Maybe fewer public calls.

Comment: @Fizz - I'd completely agree with that. When they've got a fundamentally good heart, that can be a really good (if often frustrating) quality in a leader. A [similar outburst](https://www.washingtonpost.com/nation/2021/01/11/gay-marriage-joe-biden/) of his led to the Obama administration's policy change on Gay Marriage, which was IMHO fundamental to the sudden collapse of opposition to it in the US. In this case, Biden had just visited a Ukrainian refugee center, and I think its fair to say his blood was up.

Comment: @T.E.D. yes that's seems to me to be what happened as well. Thanks for the WaPo link; I didn't realize all that had happened at the time.

Comment: If the movie Patton is to believed (it's Hollywood, so...), I think Patton got in trouble one time for joking about the US and UK dominating things after WWII, a joke which the Soviet government protested.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This seems to be a post Cold War phenomenon, and it’s even more a post [9/11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks) phenomenon as [Bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush) was the first US president to make such a statement in public. Here are some examples:

| US President | Country | Leader | Year | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [G. W. Bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush) | [Iraq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq) | [Hussein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddam_Hussein) | 2003 | [President Says Saddam Hussein Must Leave Iraq Within 48 Hours; Remarks by the President in Address to the Nation](https://georgewbush-whitehouse.archives.gov/news/releases/2003/03/20030317-7.html) |
| [Obama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama) | [Libya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libya) | [Gaddafi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muammar_Gaddafi) | 2011 | [U.S. says Libya has spoken, Gaddafi must leave now](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-libya-usa-idUSTRE71K6D520110226) |
| Obama | [Syria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syria) | [Assad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bashar_al-Assad) | 2015 | [Obama tells UN: Syria's Assad must go](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-us-canada-34385354) |
| [Trump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump) | [Venezuela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venezuela) | [Maduro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicol%C3%A1s_Maduro) | 2019 | [U.S. says Venezuela’s Maduro should go, recognizes Guaido as new leader](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/world/u-s-says-venezuelas-maduro-should-go-recognizes-guaido-as-new-leader) |
| [Biden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Biden) | [Belarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus) | [Lukashenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Lukashenko) | 2020 | [Biden vows to back Belarus opposition in removing Lukashenko](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/28/biden-vows-to-back-belarus-opposition-in-removing-lukashenko) |

Comment: Hit rate seems to be 40% at this point, not counting Putin.

Comment: @alamar Are you refering to the fact, that 2 of the countries leaders were killed? I am tallking about the first 2.

Comment: @convert since I noted that another answer is currently only referencing a statement concurrent with a military operation, I double-checked that these refer to statements separate from "actions (covert or otherwise)". I've included the titles of the links which in each case make that clear. Feel free to edit further or roll back.

Comment: I thought that maybe LBJ had made public statements about Sukarno during the 1965-66 coup d'etat and mass killings and that could be added to the list, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Not Venezuela's Chavez? Fidel Castro? Not any of the N Korean leaders? Ukraine's Viktor Yanukovych (2010-2014)?

Comment: I suppose that Biden has also said that Trump must not remain President of the United States ;-)

Comment: Tomás Estrada Palma was deposed as governor of Cuba, by the US, would that count?

Answer (score 20):

The [invasion of Panama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_invasion_of_Panama) was specifically for the purpose of removing Noriega from power there.

The speech, given by Bush, was given before most people in the US even knew that the war started.  So it had all the feeling of a speech happening before a war.  The fact that some of the operations of the war already happened, before the speech, didn't change that.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other answers I have found the following examples.

George H.W. Bush vs. Saddam Hussein. Although this was not literally a command for Saddam Hussein to resign, there is - in my opinion - hardly any difference between directly agitating the Iraqi military and people against Saddam or covertly paying "agents provocateurs" to fuel an uproar indirectly (like the US did in countless other cases). And certainly there can be no doubt about it that Bush Senior did not mean "maybe Saddam vanishes or not, I don't care" but rather strongly wished that the Iraqi people removed him from his position, and given that Bush was former CIA director, it can be speculated that he would not refrain from taking covert action to promote that goal.

- [On February 5, 1991 George H.W. Bush made a speech on Voice of America stating, "There is another way for the bloodshed to stop: and that is, for the Iraqi military and the Iraqi people to take matters into their own hands and force Saddam Hussein, the dictator, to step aside and then comply with the United Nations' resolutions and rejoin the family of peace-loving nations."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_involvement_in_regime_change)

Ronald Reagan vs. Sandinistas. Although he does not specifically address Daniel Ortega, it gets unambiguously clear from the speech, that Reagan wants regime change, and he does not want to rely on the autonomous will of the Nicaraguan people, and finally Reagan is supposing himself to be the one that has to take action. However, he had already been acting covertly under that goal for 5 years by that time. So this can be considered an attempt to save his reputation instead of being an act of upfront transparency.

- March 16, 1986, [The freedom fighters seek a political solution. They are willing to lay down their arms and negotiate to restore the original goals of the revolution, a democracy in which the people of Nicaragua choose their own government. That is our goal also, but it can only come about if the democratic resistance is able to bring pressure to bear on those who have seized power.](https://www.reaganlibrary.gov/archives/speech/address-nation-situation-nicaragua)

I think the strategy of announcing the desire (and possibly direct or covert action) for regime change was a response to the perception that covert actions often backfired against the US, especially and most importantly with respect to the US population itself. So, by publicly announcing, the administration basically wanted to cover their back, because anyone who did not disagree, counted on agreement's side.

Moreover, there are also specific and more effective means of suppressing disagreement when the administration seems to behave transparently, than there are means of suppressing public indignation and possibly legal action in case the regime change is pursued secretly.

Answer (score -1):

This is not business as usual, no matter what the US said about Saddam, Assad or Noriega in the past.  Those look the same, but they are most assuredly not the same in practice.

While there are multiple documented calls by the US for regime change, they:

- were generally frowned upon when the US first started getting into the habit of doing so.
- concerned small tinpot dictatorships, not Russia, a major nuclear power.
- not a country whom the world has a deep vested interest in seeing to effect a change of course and withdraw, *without being able to coerce in doing so*.
- With Saddam and all, the US was mostly acting on its own, for its own purposes. There was no coalition that needed to be held together and most of the world didn't particularly care, one way or the other if the US proceeded or stopped.

As Anthony Zurcher, the BBC US correspondent says [Why Biden's off-script remarks about Putin are so dangerous](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-60895392):

> The speed with which the US issued its "clarification" - later echoed by Mr Blinken - suggests the US understands the danger inherent in Mr Biden's words.

> There's a line between condemning a nation's leader - the sometimes overheated rhetoric of diplomacy - and calling for his removal. **It was a line both the Americans and the Soviets respected even at the height of the Cold War.** And it is a line that Mr Biden had apparently crossed.
>
> **"Regime change" is something powerful countries are accused of imposing on weaker ones - not what one nuclear-armed nation demands of another.**
>
> By Sunday, even some US allies were attempting to distance themselves from Mr Biden's remarks.

Biden, has, on the whole, done a very commendable job of bringing together the coalition against Russia.  He's also been very good at reminding the younger generations of the inherent constraints brought on by nuclear MAD theory.  He's preemptively outed some of their planned intentions. He's even been good at not upping the US DEFCON when Russia upped theirs earlier in the crisis.

Then he does this.  After calling Putin a war criminal the week before.

The fact that many of us will feel that he is right does not make saying it **publicly** any less of a gaffe.  He got elected to a position which requires keeping a tight lid on one's mouth when necessary.

---

Another indication that this was not normal practice is that Biden had to [publicly disown his own statement](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/600055-biden-putin-comments-were-an-expression-of-moral-outrage-not-policy):

> "But I want to make it clear: I wasn’t then nor am I now articulating a policy change," Biden said. "I was expressing moral outrage that I feel, and I make no apologies for it."

Now, if this was just like previous POTUS regime change calls, why did he have to do that?

p.s. I am not questioning Biden's competence, which I otherwise would rate highly in this crisis.  Nor should anyone put words into my mouth about his age - a criticism often raised by Trump who often looked way more doddery himself.

Comment: Just a thought; why not *ask* what you "certainly consider to be the larger question behind the question" as a proper Stack Exchange question to allow others to express their views as well rather than hijack my question to try to make it about something that it isn't and then have yours as the only answer to it? I try to ask fairly low-temperature questions that can be answered with facts. That I've done so here is not an accident or oversight. Ask this as a new question and let everyone answer!

Comment: It's not the only answer.  And I apologize and did not mean to cause offense or annoy you.  But what I find concerning is that the answers so far treat it as business as usual.  It is not.  The US had the power to get away with the other guys.  It can't here.  That's amply supported by the BBC guy.

Comment: In Stack Exchange "business as usual" is answering the question as asked; as written in the question post. SE works so well because we all stick to business as usual. To me this is an opportunistic airing of a personal viewpoint and does not qualify as a Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: OK you've made your point the first time.  I was able to read it perfectly well.  Consider it a reframing then.  All the answers so far:  no big deal.  Which isn't borne out by international reactions to it.  So, just my personal opinion?  I think not.  What is also missing in the answers is that it was almost unprecented for a Western government to  publicly advocate regime change outside of wartime when the US first started on the practice.

Comment: @uhoh I'd have to agree with Italian here. While I'm sure your intentions were good, a pure answer of the question as currently stated without additional context is simply misleading about the rarity and impact of the event that you explicitly referenced at the beginning of the question, whether it is intended to be so or not. This answer provides much-needed context.

Comment: @reirab the question is indeed about frequency, but it's the *answers* not the question that provide information about the rarity. I'm seeing about a half-dozen postwar instances; so somewhat rare but increasing in frequency. That's how Q&A works. As for impact, that's outside the scope of the question *by design* as it is likely to attract primarily based opinions as answers, which is precisely what happened here and should not have. The average reader understands that SE and Wikipedia are fundamentally different animals, and if they want background and context they go to the other site.

Comment: @reirab if we are going to stick with how SE works (despite being open to (almost) the entire internet) then what is "certainly consider(ed) to be the larger question behind the question" deserves its own question post with its own searchable title and the opportunity for anyone who would like to post an answer, providing future readers with the opportunity to read all of them. The question or its answers (if not closed) can link back here for fact-based answers on frequency if/when necessary or helpful. And I think that there is some evidence now that this is how some others view it as well.

Comment: @uhoh You're waaaay off base with that. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t  Seems as if the point of your question was to try to minimize the seriousness of Biden's gaffe - something he does often, and you and the echo chamber here seem upset that this answer dared venture into questioning Biden's competence with actual evidence. Can't do that to an 80-year-old who literally displays multiple dementia symptoms and whose handlers won't allow to answer live questions, right?

Comment: @JustMe *Yikes, I'm being Rorschached!* It doesn't seem like that at all. I really am simply interested in answer(s) that establish how frequent this action is. I'm not maximizing or minimizing, taking a stance, pushing a position, making light of nor overemphasizing anything. I just wanna know how frequent or rare this is. If someone wants to go deeper (and/or soapbox) they should *ask a new question* allowing anyone to answer and link back here for the basic facts. There is something about this site; some of you folks are absolutely terrified of a simple, spartan, black & white question.

Comment: @uhoh re. "soapbox"  I am getting somewhat tired of your allegations.  My initial phrasing was needlessly argumentative, which *I have apologized for and edited the answer*.  That said, the question is fairly narrow:  was this done before?  Technically, yes and other answers have given examples.  Answers which I don't disagree with.  But are those examples really similar to asking for regime change **in Russia**?  I don't think so and I have given specific differences in attributes.  The fact there is ample press coverage with my concerns shows it is not merely me "soapboxing".

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica many laudable and compelling things have been said from atop soap boxes. What makes something soapboxing is the mechanical portability of the device, not the nature of the words. The remedy to my concern that I've proposed several times above should make it clear the nature of my complaint. Let's all stay within the constraints of what makes Stack Exchange great! Ask "Why is Biden's "For God’s sake, this man cannot remain in power" widely considered a gaffe to be walked back unlike previous US presidents' "gotta go" statements about heads of state?"

Comment: That way asked as a question you have the option to add your answer (when you post a question there' even a little box to tick saying "answer my own question") *as an answer to the question as asked* which is a plus and it allows others the opportunity to write answers as well, and since answers match the question and its title, they are more likely to be found by future readers in search results. This is so much better than setting up a soap box on this page to address something that wasn't asked. I will be more than happy to add a line within my short question linking to the other question.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica or I am happy to ask that proposed question (if it hasn't been already) and include in the post something like "In my previous question, several examples of X, however this seems somewhat different in that there has been widespread use of the term 'gaffe' to describe it, and instances of the White House spokes person, other administration figures and the president themself to clarify it have been labeled 'walking it back'..." It doesn't matter who asks it, what matters as it is now the question may be answered by anyone, and we preserve the norms and standards of SE

Comment: [Why is Biden's "(Putin) ...cannot remain in power" widely considered a gaffe to be walked back while previous US presidents have said similar?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/72267/16047)

Comment: @JustMe ditto..